# Windows 10 won't boot off USB media while Linux boots fine

Tags: windows, macos, boot, usb, windows-10

I have a desktop computer with new HDD that I am trying to install windows on. I only have a mac to create the bootable media for it. I got a copy of windows 10 ISO from microsoft web site and used `dd` and `Boot Camp Assistant` to create a bootable UBS drive. Neither work - when I select the USB media from the list in the boot menu it will say that the media is not bootable.

I tried burning a linux distribution on the same USB stick and it boots fine. I tried Windows 7 image and it doesn't work.

The computer is bit of a legacy with Asus P7P55-M (Intel P55 Express chipset) - just in cases this could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: How about WinPE, which is designed to run from removable media? See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613860.aspx. It is a minimalist OS, though.

Comment: WinPE is the installation environment, so if he can't get to the installer, he obviously can't get to WinPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create the USB on a Mac. That's the problem.

Install VirtualBox, create a Windows VM (easy to find ISOs). Once you have a Windows machine, there are many free tools that do this great. Rufus, YUMI, and many more.

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I've ever been able to get a Windows USB stick working with is Microsoft's own USB stick tool, downloadable here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

This is Windows-only, though, so you might have to use VirtualBox or something to get it working.